# How to split dictionary keys and change the type in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am tasked with figuring out which 'keys' in a dictionary are 300 level or above. An example of a dictionary like this would be {'CSCI 160': 4, 'CSCI 330': 3, 'MATH 208': 3, 'EE 201":4}. How would I go about splitting the keys and converting the numerical portion into an integer?

Comment: use a list comprehension

Comment: What did _you_ try to do _your_ homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a new dictionary with the key and value pairs from the original dictionary, but only if the value is greater than or equal to 300.

```
filtered_dict = {key: val for key, val in my_dict.items() if int(key.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]) >= 300}
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply! unfortunately, when I tried running the program it came back with: builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for what is required!